# Issue with displaying text on an image

Tags: html

I am buliding a custom email template and i am trying to put text in a specific position on an image. This template is built dynamically via [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) on a camunda workflow model.

The codes below can be tested/viewed at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .top-left {
      position: absolute;
      top: 170px;
      left: 250px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img data-imagetype="External" src='img_snow_wide.jpg' width="1000" height="600">
    <div class="top-left">{{happyBirthday}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you may see ***{{happyBirthday}}***, which will display values dynamically, is showing on the desired place on the image when using CODE A.

However the template received via email shows the value for ***{{happyBirthday}}*** below the image. I was able to get the snippet of code, CODE B,  from the elements tab on chrome console via inspect,

**CODE B**

```html
<div>
  <style>
    <!-- .rps_9d84 .x_container {
      text-align: left;
      color: white
    }
    
    .rps_9d84 .x_top-left {
      top: 170px;
      left: 250px;
      color: #000080
    }
    
    -->
  </style>
  <div class="rps_9d84">
    <div>
      <div class="x_container">
        <img data-imagetype="External" src="img_snow_wide.jpg" width="1000" height="600">
        <div class="x_top-left">{{happyBirthday}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you may see the two codes are similar in the key aspects of the css code i.e. *top-left*, which determines the position of the dynamic text on the image.

I am not an html expert and i do not see the difference between the two sets of code. Could someone point out what i am missing here ?

Comment: What's with th comments in in code B `<!-- -->`

Comment: @mplungjan i copied CODE B here as is from the html element from the email received. It is not there in CODE A so not sure where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **position: absolute;** property on .x_top-left

Answer (score 1):

Since your **top-left** class element doesn't seem to apply the **absolute position** style (in CODE B), which will by  default always be placed under or next to the previous element.

Try to set the position element with the !important flag.

```css
    .top-left {
      position: absolute !important;
      top: 170px;
      left: 250px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David, i added that but there is no change in the result. So the issue seems to be the styles show up commented in the email template sent from the workflow, which will be CODE B, whereas i have not applied any comments in CODE A, which in simpler terms is the parent of CODE B. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Ok. Then it seems to me that de parse of your mustache templates commets all styles.
so you may need to link in the css as element ether in the template or somehow in the parser.

Examplte import of a css with mustache
`
<link href="{{{resources}}}/core/css/hello.css" rel="stylesheet">
`

Comment: Hi David, as i am not able to do any changes to the parser itself, that will require some work from our developers to implement this if i understood correctly, could you please direct me to a link for " you may need to link in the css as element ether in the template ". Changing the template is the best i can do atm

Comment: Hi Bisoux, Here is a java example of a Mustache Template. 
Github Amdegregorio EmailWithMustacheTemplate] (https://github.com/amdegregorio/EmailWithMustacheTemplates/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/sendEmail.html)

You may also check the camuda plugin you're using to send mail. They may have a link how to customize the email template with your own css. I thing you just need to do it in a separate css file and not in the mail template.